# Merge/join seq of seqs

Tags: f#, sequence

Slowly getting the hang of List matching and tail recursion, I needed a function which 'stitches' a list of lists together leaving off intermediate values (easier to show than explain):

merge [[1;2;3];[3;4;5];[5;6;7]] //-> [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]

The code for the List.merge function looks like this:

```
///Like concat, but removes first value of each inner list except the first one
let merge lst = 
    let rec loop acc lst = 
        match lst with
        | [] -> acc
        | h::t -> 
            match acc with
            | [] -> loop (acc @ h) t
            | _ -> loop (acc @ (List.tl h)) t //first time omit first value
    loop [] lst
```

*(OK, it's not quite like concat, because it only handles two levels of list)*

Question: How to do this for a Seq of Seqs (without using a mutable flag)?

**UPDATE** (re comment from Juliet):
My code creates 'paths' composed of 'segments' which are based on an option type:

```
type SegmentDef = Straight of float | Curve of float * float
let Project sampleinterval segdefs = //('clever' code here)
```

When I do a List.map (Project 1.) ListOfSegmentDefs, I get back a list where each segment begins on the same point where the previous segment ends. I want to join these lists together to get a Path, keeping only the 'top/tail' of each overlap - but I don't need to do a 'Set', because I know that I don't have any other duplicates.

Comment: Its not exactly clear what you're referring to by "intermediate values". Are you trying to flatten the list and remove duplicates at the same time? Trying to chop off the first item of each sub list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially the same as your first solution, but a little more succinct:

```
let flatten l =
    seq {
        yield Seq.hd (Seq.hd l) (* first item of first list *)
        for a in l do yield! (Seq.skip 1 a) (* other items *)
    }
```

**[Edit to add]:**

If you need a List version of this code, use append `|> Seq.to_list` at the end of your method:

```
let flatten l =
    seq {
        yield Seq.hd (Seq.hd l) (* first item of first list *)
        for a in l do yield! (Seq.skip 1 a) (* other items *)
    } |> Seq.to_list
```

Comment: Also, if you want a list version of the code, is just easier to use seq { ... } |> Seq.to_list rather than rolling your own list version.

Comment: But will it 'eat' lists of lists too? I still haven't grokked when Seq, List and #Seq cooperate or not.

Comment: If by "will it 'eat' lists", you mean "is the function generalized to work on seq's and list's simultaneously", then yes, you can pass an object of type "list list 'a" and get back a "list 'a". Keep in mind that seq is a typedef of IEnumerable<_>, and list's implement the IEnumerable<_> interface.

Comment: `seq { ... } |> Seq.to_list` is just `[...]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
let merge = function
  | [] -> []
  | xs::xss -> xs @ [for _::xs in xss do yield! xs]
```

or:

```
let merge = function
  | [] -> []
  | xs::xss -> xs @ List.collect List.tail xss
```

Comment: I can't believe there is not any merge function provided by the .NET framework or built-in F# libs?

Comment: @knocte: What surprises me is that APIs like `Set` and `Map` are full of functions like `exists`, `forAll` and `partition` that make no attempt to leverage the underlying data structure and, therefore, offer no particular advantage (and are never used IME) but functions like `merge` and `mapReduce` that could leverage the underlying data structure to good effect are absent. `SortedDictionary` and `Map` are both sorted dictionaries but neither offer a function to get the largest key-value pair other than by enumerating the entire dictionary.

Comment: how to suggest it then? github issue or uservoice?

Comment: I'd wait until the official F# is ready to start accepting user contributions.

Comment: @JonHarrop wait a sec, I've just found in the docs what appears to be an operator for doing this! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx#sectionToggle1 , should I post it as an answer or am I missing something?