# F# function to convert a n-dimensional list to 1-dimensional list

Tags: f#

I'm attempting a few minor tasks in F# to help get a handle on the language.

I would like to write a function that takes a n-dimensional list and returns a 1-dimensional list containing all the elements from each dimension.

For example, if the input was the following 3-dimensional list: [[[1;2];[3;4]];[[5;6];[7;8]]], the output would be: [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]

For 2-dimensions -> 1-dimension the function is pretty straightforward:

```
let coalesce list= List.collect(fun item -> item) list
```

Here is my attempt to generalize this to n-dimensions:

```
let rec coalesce (list, dimension) = 
    if dimension = 1 then list 
    else coalesce (List.collect(fun item -> item) list, dimension - 1)
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
'a list list
but given a
'a list
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a list'

The issue is here:

```
List.collect(fun item -> item) list
```

There's obviously something wrong with my thinking.  What's the proper way to write this sort of function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502447/f-merge-join-seq-of-seqs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is not well-typed, but here's a sample that works on `IEnumerable`s and returns a `list<obj>`:

```
let rec coalesce(list:System.Collections.IEnumerable, dim) =
    [
        if dim=1 then for x in list do yield x
        else
            for x in list do
                match x with
                | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as s ->
                    yield! coalesce(s, dim-1)
                | _ -> failwith "bad shape"
    ]
printfn "%A" (coalesce([1;2], 1))
printfn "%A" (coalesce([[1;2];[3;4]], 2))
printfn "%A" (coalesce([[[1;2];[3;4]];[[5;6];[7]]], 3))
```

You can also write

```
let rec flatten(list:System.Collections.IEnumerable) =
    [for x in list do
        match x with
        | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable as s -> yield! flatten(s)
        | _ -> yield x
    ]
```

which is more general, e.g.

```
let weird : obj list = [[box [1;2]; box 3]; 4; [box [5;6]; box 7]]
printfn "%A" (flatten weird)
```

EDIT

@Jon Harrop suggested another strategy - create a new type for nested lists:

```
type NestedListElement<'T> = //'
    | L of NestedListElement<'T> list //'
    | V of 'T //'

let rec flatten nlist = 
    [for x in nlist do 
        match x with 
        | L l -> yield! flatten l
        | V v -> yield v
    ] 

let nested = [L[L[V 1;V 2]; V 3]; V 4; L[L[V 5;V 6]; V 7]] 
printfn "%A" (flatten nested)
```

Comment: "This operation is not well-typed". In F# but other languages don't have a problem, of course.

Answer (score 2):

The F# type system cannot express this. The most common solution is to create a new type representing nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I've a bit knowledge of F# syntax, this is solution in C#, may be it helps:

```
namespace FlatEnumerable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arr = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }, { { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } } };
            foreach (var i in arr.Flat())
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    static class Enumerable2
    {
        public static IEnumerable Flat(this IEnumerable source)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                var enu = item as IEnumerable;
                if (enu != null)
                    foreach (var c in enu.Flat())
                        yield return c;
                else
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I belive it can be improved in F# by using pattern matching instead of casting and checking for null.

Answer (score 0):

No, the problem is that `coalesce` takes a list of lists and the compiler doesn't know that `List.collect(fun item -> item) list` always returns a list of lists (as a matter of fact the compiler can't know that because it's not true). However since that's what you pass in as the argument to `coalesce` the compiler would need to know that in order to allow that call.

Comment: Oops.  You're right.  List.collect(fun item -> item) won't always return a list of lists.  I'll edit my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I Took the nested List idea and tried to write a neater version:

```
type NestedListElement<'T> = //'
| L of NestedListElement<'T> list //'
| V of 'T //'

let nested = [L[L[V 1;V 2]; V 3]; V 4; L[L[V 5;V 6]; V 7]] 

let flatten n1 = 
            let rec traverseNestedList nl = match nl with      
                                            | V c -> [c]           
                                            | L a -> List.collect traverseNestedList a
            List.collect traverseNestedList n1 

let res7 = nested |> flatten
```